# Scss compiler error: no mixin named transition

Tags: meteor, sass, bower, mixins

I have a meteor app which uses bower components.

When I try to run the app I got an error: `Scss compiler error: no mixin named transition`

which comes from the line of: `@include transition(.2s ease-out);`

What could be cause of this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@include expects a mixin. In this case it is expecting a mixin named 'transition' and I think you are trying to apply 'transition' as a css property.

Check this page out: http://sass-lang.com/guide

Comment: I had commented out `@mixin transition($args:200ms) {
    -webkit-transition: $args;
    -moz-transition: $args;
    -o-transition: $args;
    -ms-transition: $args;
    transition: $args;
}` Thats what you get working on project created by others. :D