# Error: no mixin named transition with Susy in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, sass, susy, susy-sass, storefront

I'm compiling Woocommerce's Storefront theme using Gulp and Sass and came across an error with one of the mixins:

Error in plugin "sass"
Message:
    storefront/assets/css/woocommerce/woocommerce.scss
Error: no mixin named transition
        on line 2831 of storefront/assets/css/woocommerce/woocommerce.scss, in mixin `@content`
        from line 52 of node_modules/susy/sass/susy/language/susy/_breakpoint-plugin.scss, in mixin `susy-media`
        from line 1881 of storefront/assets/css/woocommerce/woocommerce.scss

> > ```
> >                          @include transition( left 0.3s ease-out );
> > ```

Any ideas?

PS. There were some other problems with the Susy but downgrading to the susy-2.2.14 solve them.

---

**EDIT:** Solved by adding:

```
@mixin transition($args...) { 
    -webkit-transition: $args; 
    -moz-transition: $args; 
    -ms-transition: $args; 
    -o-transition: $args; 
    transition: $args; 
}
```

Comment: Solved by adding: 

@mixin transition($args...) {
  -webkit-transition: $args;
  -moz-transition: $args;
  -ms-transition: $args;
  -o-transition: $args;
  transition: $args;
}

Answer (score 0):

Either there is no mixin `transition`, it is not included\deleted or apply [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35482388/scss-compiler-error-no-mixin-named-transition).

> @include expects a mixin. In this case it is expecting a mixin named
>   'transition' and I think you are trying to apply 'transition' as a css
>   property.
>
> Check this page out: http://sass-lang.com/guide